# Xamarin android project doesn't build

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I am trying to create a splash screen for an Android Xamarin app

the splash screen should be a background with a logo on top of it.

so far I managed to display the background.

using this layout

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
    android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />

<!-- background image -->
  <item>
    <bitmap
      android:gravity="fill"
      android:src="@drawable/Splashscreen" />
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

The splash screen works fine

Adding the logo creates the problem. ( just added this code after the background item)

```
 <!-- logo -->
      <item android:top="200dp">
        <bitmap
          android:src="@drawable/Logo"/>
      </item>
```

The app stops building.

and I get no error message back other than an error that has occurred during Building.

here is the style I'm using

```
<style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/SplashScreenWithLogo</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Delete bin and obj folders, clean solution. Also look a the build logs.

Comment: getting these errors in the build logs
´verify android SDK installed´
´removing android SDK errors´
I found out that if I wait for a few minutes the project builds
but after any changes, it happens again and I have to wait a few mins again...

Comment: Show actual error thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a look in the build logs, I got these two errors

```
verify android SDK installed
removing android SDK errors
```

so after some internet research, the problem was solved by updating the emulator